# Adding libraries to project

Tags: c++, qt, static-libraries, apr

I'm new to Qt, and got following error to my C++ project:

```
fatal error: apr_pools.h: No such file or directory
```

I installed apr from https://apr.apache.org/compiling_unix.html and compiled it by executing:

```
 ./configure
 make
 make install
```

But I have no idea now how to link proper files to my project.

Comment: How are you building the project?

Comment: Simply by 'Build all'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by adding external library. The result in .pro file is as below:

```
unix:!macx: LIBS += -L/usr/local/apr/lib/ -lapr-1

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/apr/include/apr-1
DEPENDPATH += /usr/local/apr/include/apr-1
```

But anyway thanks everyone for their time and good intentions :)

Comment: That is one hell of a relative pathname. Of course probably if you ever move your project to a different place it will stop working. Couldn't you just say `-L/usr/local/apr/lib` as that path is unlikely to change. Another good possibility is `-L$$PWD/../local/apr/lib` and then make sure that you install into a local/ subdir that is parallel to your project folders

Comment: @Brandin Yes, u are right. I changed it in my solution. Thank u a lot! Before I just did it by a qt creator which generate such a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

This is not about linking but about preprocessing for now. (the preprocessor = the program or part of the compiler which read all the lines beginning with a '#' and replace macro and insert included headers.)
The preprocessor can't find your header

see http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qmake-project-files.html#declaring-other-libraries

you have to add an include path to where your additional headers are.

[EDIT]

But there are no packages in your distribution ?

What is you OS, or linux distribution ?

if you want to install the bins and headers, maybe something like `./configure --prefix=/usr ; sudo make install` should be needed or copy the files directly (adapt to your system and for the makefile)

[/EDIT]

Answer (score 0):

You must:

- Specity in your `.pro` where header files must be searched: something like `win32:INCLUDEPATH += "C:/mylibs/extra headers"
  unix:INCLUDEPATH += "/home/user/extra headers"`
- You must specify which library must to be linked: something like
  `win32:LIBS += /mylibs/lib.so
  unix:LIBS += c:/mylibs/library`